# dos select seguidos

Tags: php, html

Tengo que hacer este ejercicio antes del viernes y no me termina de salir, me explicaré.
Tengo en una base de datos países, ciudades y datos de esas ciudades, a la cual conecto bien.
Necesito hacer dos select en html seguidos, uno de países y otro de ciudades.
Hasta que no seleccione algo del primero no aparecerá nada en el segundo y al seleccionar de éste, aparecerá una tabla con datos de la tercera tabla.
Pues bien, el primer select funciona, pero el segundo no y ya le he dado muchas vueltas, pero no me sale.
Este es el código que he hecho:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WORLD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","");
            //define("BD","world");
            $BD="world";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('world.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
            echo "<h1>EJERCICIO CONSULTA DE PAISES POR REGIONES</h1>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action=\"index.php\">";
            $sql1='SELECT Region FROM country';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
            echo "Selecciona Region: <select name='campo_busqueda1'>
                <option>Selecciona...</option>";
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo '<option value="'.$fila1["Region"].'">'.$fila1["Region"].'</option>';
            };
            $region=$_POST["campo_busqueda1"];
            echo "</select>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
            <br>";echo $region;
            $sql2='SELECT Name FROM country WHERE Region="$region"';
            $resultado2=$db->query($sql2);
            echo "Selecciona Pais: <select name='campo_busqueda2'>
                <option>Selecciona...</option>";
            while(($fila2=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo '<option value="'.$fila2["Name"].'">'.$fila2["Name"].'</option>';
            };
            echo "</select>
                <input type='submit' value='Enviar'><br>
            </form>";
        ?>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Poblacion</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    /*foreach(){
                        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                    }*/
                ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que tratas de hacer se llama select dependiente (select dependent en inglés), date una vuelta por este link, te ayudará bastante: https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Gracias David, pero solo puedo usar php

Comment: Para este ejercicio necesariamente debes usar un lenguaje del lado del cliente (javascript), para que se refresque el segundo select una vez que seleccionas un país, puede que lo estés haciendo bien en tu código pero el cambio no se ve en la página porque no hay un javascript o jquery que muestre ese cambio en el cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo puedes realizar de diferentes maneras, primero debes definir los paises como ya lo tienes:

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WORLD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","toor");
            //define("BD","world");
            $BD="prueba";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('world.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
        $sql1='SELECT id, nombre FROM paises';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
    ?>
        <h1>EJERCICIO CONSULTA DE PAISES POR REGIONES</h1>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action='ciudades.php'>

           Selecciona Region: <select name='campo_busqueda1' id="campo_busqueda1">
                <option>Selecciona...</option>
    <?php
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
           echo '<option value="'.$fila1["id"].'">'.$fila1["nombre"].'</option>';
            };
    ?>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

dicho archivo solo muestra un formulario con un select con el listado de paises algo asi:
[image: paises]

una vez presionado el boton enviar el **id** del **option** seleccionado es enviado a otro archivo php donde se procesa las ciudades:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WORLD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","toor");
            //define("BD","world");
            $BD="prueba";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('world.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
        $sql1='SELECT id, nombre FROM paises';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);

        $sql2='SELECT id, nombre FROM ciudades WHERE pais_id ='.$_POST['campo_busqueda1'];
            $resultado2=$db->query($sql2);
    ?>
        <h1>EJERCICIO CONSULTA DE PAISES POR REGIONES</h1>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action=''>

           Selecciona Region: <select name='campo_busqueda1' id="campo_busqueda1">
                <option>Selecciona...</option>
    <?php
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
        if($_POST['campo_busqueda1'] == $fila1["id"]){
           echo '<option value="'.$fila1["id"].'" selected="selected" >'.$fila1["nombre"].'</option>';      
        }else{
         echo '<option value="'.$fila1["id"].'" >'.$fila1["nombre"].'</option>';
        }            
       };
    ?>
            </select><br>
    Selecciona Ciudad: <select name='campo_ciudad' id="campo_ciudad">
                <option>Selecciona...</option>
    <?php
            while(($fila1=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
         echo '<option value="'.$fila1["id"].'" >'.$fila1["nombre"].'</option>';
       };
    ?>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
            </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

el resultado seria algo como esto:

[image: resultado_ciudades]
Para establecer el selected de paises lo que hago es mediate un if determinar si el id del pais escogido es igual al id de el listado de paises existentes y alli defino el selected, debes validar mas cosas como que escoja una opcion es decir un required y mas pero es un ejemplo basico.

Espero te sirva de guia..!!

Comment: Nota..debes construir la tabla con las ciudades dado que yo realize un select con las ciudades en base al pais seleccionado previamente